# using google to search for webpages from a given time period

Tags: google-search

I would like to search google for a given string, eg. "how to train zombies", but I only want the newest information on this exciting topic, say all information written after 2013.  Google has an advanced search option that lets me only search webpages younger than a prescribed age, but I don't just want webpages that are written after 2013, I also want older webpages that has been updated after 2013--eg. a blog post from 2010 that somebody has commented on later than 2013; so that my google search will give me not just webpages created after 2013, but also eg. questions asked on stack exchange in 2012 where the latest answer is after 2013.

All suggestions are greatly appreciated
thanks :)